# Django - Display specific JSON parts only

Tags: python, json, django

I have a file that has some JSON data .. I click a button and it renders on my HTML page ... However I only want to see specific pieces from the file

Here is my view.py

```
def read_file(request):
    f = open('output.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    context = {'file_content': file_content}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Here is my html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Test Test 123
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
        <form action="/open_file/" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Get Details">
            <br><br>
            {% csrf_token %} 
            {{ file_content | linebreaks }}
        </form>  

  </body>

  </html>
```

In the textfile the JSON looks like this

```
====================Response====================
{
  "responseBody": {
    "errorId": 200,
    "errorMsg": "ok",
    "userDetails": {
      "fname": "Andy",
      "lname": "Test",
      "status": "YES",
      "email": "testuser@.com",
      "userName": "usernametest1212",
      "deviceDetails": {
        "type": "Mobile",
        "osVersion": "5.0.0",
        "nickname": "Test Telephone",
        "deviceModel": "Samsung"
      },
      "devicesDetails": [
        {
          "type": "Watch",
          "osVersion": "iOS 11",
          "email": null,
          "hasWatch": yes
        },
    }
```

What i would like to see is the following:

```
ErrorMsg
UserDetails - username and email 
deviceDetails - type and device model
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to read your json file and extract only the required information. And render that information in the HTML

**Ex:**

```
import json
def read_file(request):
    with open('output.txt') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    context = {'ErrorMsg': data["errorMsg"], 
               "username": data['userDetails']['userName'], 
               "email": data['userDetails']['email'], 
               "type": data['userDetails']['deviceDetails']['type'], 
               "deviceModel": data['userDetails']['deviceDetails']['deviceModel']}

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Comment: Cheers ... Throwing an error .. I will keep digging

JSONDecodeError at /read_file/

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: its probably because have `====================Response====================` in the json file. remove that and it should work

Comment: Nope same ... No worries tho i will keep digging